# Php - Array to string conversion

Tags: php

I want to output all records in my database. So far so good, but when I loop through it, php gives me an error " Array to string conversion ".

- I added an index to the array but then it does just output obviously the first or secound ( etc. ) column.

  ```
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database","root","");
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM de');
  $stmt ->execute();
  $result = $stmt ->fetchAll();

  if (is_array($result) || is_object($result))
  {
      foreach ($result[0] as $value)
          {
              echo "<table><tr><td>'$value'</td></tr></table>";
          }
  }
  ```

So, with the index, it does work. But I need all records, not just one.

I appreciate every comment and help!

Comment: It's `foreach ($result as $value){}` as you've have not determined that `$result[0]` is indeed an array.

Comment: foreach ($result  as $value)  should be like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start with a nested loop. I also wonder if you want a table for every value

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database","root","");
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM de');
$stmt ->execute();
$result = $stmt ->fetchAll();

if (is_array($result) || is_object($result))
{
    foreach ($result as $row){  //Go through every row in the result
        echo('<table>');
        foreach ($row as $value){    //Go through every value in the row
            echo "<tr><td>'$value'</td></tr>";
        }
        echo('</table>');
    }
}
```

This will print every row as a new table, but you can search out the variation you want.

Comment: I love you :) Thank you verry much for your help! It did work. Btw, if you wouldn't mind to answer, why do I need two loops, to get all records?

Comment: You need two loops, because you need to get two separate things: 1) Every row from the results. And then 2) Every value from each row.

Comment: Of course. I wanted already but I've to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer

Comment: OK! I'm not going anywhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

A nested foreach loop should work.

```
foreach ($result as $values)
{
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo "<table><tr><td>'$value'</td></tr></table>";
  }
}
```

Comment: That will just print 'Array Array Array' all down the screen. OP wants every value from every row.

Comment: Ah I see. The shouted "no" wasn't necessary though ;)

Comment: There! I've stopped shouting :-)

Comment: Hehe my feelings have now been unhurt. I'll stop crying now :-D

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to nested loops, if you know the number of fields and said number is constant for each execution; A state that's found in most situations; You can use `vsprintf ()` to print out the rows.

Quick example:

```
$result = {{'John', 'Doe'}, {'Sarah', 'Jane'}};
$output = '<table>';
foreach ($result as $row) {
   $output .= vsprintf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", $row);
}
echo $output."</table>";
```

Cuts down a bit on the code, and quite a bit on the code complexity. The template for the rows themselves can also be extracted to a variable (or template view), outside of the loop, to make the code even cleaner.